# How to Only select the Columns which can be casted to Numeric Else ignore the column in Spark Sql?

Tags: mysql, apache-spark

I have tried a lot of things but could not find a proper solution of how to select columns which can be casted to Double or Numeric when Initially I have all the columns of type `String`. And ignore the rest of the columns.

Suppose I have 100 Columns of type String initially and I want to check which columns can be casted to Numeric and just select them and ignore all the other columns.

For example -

```
StructType(
    StructField(SnapshotDate,StringType,true), 
    StructField(Country,StringType,true),
    StructField(Region,Stri‌​ngType,true),
    StructField(Probabil‌​ity,StringType,true)‌​, 
    StructField(BookingAmount,StringType,true), 
    StructField(RevenueAmount,StringType,true)
)
```

Here I just want to select `RevenueAmount`, `Probability` and `BookingAmount`. Other Columns are either String type or Date, So i would like to ignore them.

Is there a way to do that?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please provide with the code you tried. Do not ask to write whole program. If you have tried something come up with it and ask the doubts.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `schema` method in the `DataFrame` to get at `StructType` which describe the schema of your Dataframe.

A `StructType` is a set of `StructField`s composing your Dataframe schema, you can return a `Seq[StructField]` from your schema (returned by `schema` on your DataFrame) using the `seq` method.

Now you can simply iterate over the schema and keeping just the desired columns using the `map` method.

```
val df = //your Dataframe definition
val schema = df.schema
val desiredColumns = schema.seq.map(structfield => 
  if (structfield.dataType.simpleString //pass some condition) structfiled.name
val newDf = df.select(desiredColumns: _*)
```

**Notes :**

- the `: _*` notation is using in scala to tell the compiler to pass the values inside and Array one by one (not the whole the Array as single parameter)
- the `simpleString` method return a `String` representation for a `DataType` here's some examples (`String` => `string` and `Int` => `int`) note that the representation start with a lower case instead of an Uppercase

Comment: Wouldn't you get a `Nil` when the if condition won't be satisfied ? And wouldn't that result in a `Seq` with empty values (maybe of type `Any`)? And wouldn't that throw an error in the line with `newDf`?

Comment: @ShubhamKedia Please add these details to your question instead of adding it up in comments. Thanks.